# If I took a debt of 5 dollars, how much money do I have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to make sense of negative numbers, I remember reading an explanation of negative numbers like this:

If I took a debt of \$$5$, then this means that I now have -\$$5$, because I have to give back \$$5$. But is this really true? I mean yes, I do have -\$$5$, but don't I also have \$$5$? I mean that's the whole point why I took a debt of \$$5$, so I can have \$$5$! So is the correct answer that after taking the debt of \$$5$, I would have -\$$5$ and \$$5$?

Comment: Within the context of the balance between you and your creditor, you as the debtor do in fact wield a negative amount. In the broader domain, say of monetary leverage, negative values don't mean as much. But no you do not have both negative and positive 5 dollars. If you have \$10 spending limit on a credit card then you have positive 10 dollars with respect to purchasing power. If you owe the cc company \$5 then you with respect to the cc company are worth presently negative \$5 and simultaneously (supposing same spending limit) have a positive \$5 value with respect to your purchasing power.

Comment: Yes, you are right in that this example is confusing. Here is a hopefully clearer example, which is essentially equivalent to the example you are interested in. Suppose you have 2 people, say A and B. From the perspective of A, if A receives 5 dollars from B, this transaction can be thought of as positive 5 dollars, while if A gives 10 dollars to B, this transaction can be thought of as negative 10 dollars. You could have actually represented things in the opposite way, but what matters is that you know well what something positive and what something negative represent, in your convention.

Comment: I think the idea of "I took a debt of $\$5$" is not that I received $\$5$ as a loan and must pay it back later, it is that I did **not** receive any money but now I owe $\$5.$ For example I wanted a sandwich but had no money so I gave the cashier an IOU for $\$5$ and ate the sandwich. I now owe $\$5$ and have no money with which to pay back the debt. The hot dog in the answer below is only slightly more complicated, the money passed through your hands to get the hot dog but at the end of the game you have no money and still owe the five dollars to Jake.

Comment: @David K  In line with the IOU analogy, what would a five-dollar bill be worth? The sandwich shop does not owe you $5. (It could, if say you complained about your sandwich, and they give you if not a cash refund then in-store credit, but that's besides the point).  There exists a lack of symmetry to the positive values.

Comment: @11qq00 Actually the IOU is a form of money, like a $\$5$ bill although not as negotiable. I actually don't like the money example much because it's too abstract; it's your **net worth** that is negative (assuming you really had no other assets to begin with), but there's no tangible object you can point to that represents your net worth. The monetary instruments we exchange themselves always have positive value.

Comment: @David K "The monetary instruments we exchange themselves always have positive value."  precisely. The less abstract way I think to represent negatives & positives in terms of money is a balance. If you have absolutely no other assets and presently owe someone a positive amount of money, then you are worth a negative amount of money. Since most persons do have some material assets of monetary value, the relevant matter within small scope is the balance between two parties (negative, 0, or positive owed from A to B <==> positive, 0, or negative owed from B to A).

Comment: Of course conversions aren't always equal (e.g. in-store credit has less use than nationally accepted currency) but the basic idea of negative versus positive balance makes sense with respect to one party regarding one other party.

Answer (score 1):

The kicker here is that although you have $\$5$, it doesn't belong to you. You had to borrow the money from someone else, so you have to pay them back at some point. For example, let's say I went to a baseball game with my friend, Jake. I want to buy a a $\$5$ hotdog, but I forgot my wallet at home. To pay for the food, I borrow money from Jake, who I will pay back the next dat. I now owe Jake money. I have to give $\$5$ to Jake tomorrow, so I lose $\$5$ when I pay him back, so the whole ordeal costs me $-\$5$.

Think of positive and negative whole numbers like an elevator. If I ride an elevator $5$ floors up, I move $+5$ floors upward. If I want to go from Floor $5$ to Floor $2$, I have to go down $2$ floors,  meaning I travel $-2$ floors.

Comment: The total distance however that you traveled from floor5 to floor2  is the absolute value, i.e. 3 floors. But you did travel negative three floors in the vertical direction, counting down as negative and up as positive (which makes sense since going against gravity takes more energy, a positive amount, whereas going with gravity none or even a surplus if harnessed albe not 100% conversion, and since is conventional directionality of y-axis).

Comment: That's a good observation, thanks for the thoughts. I saw the elevator concept years ago on the children's math cartoon, Cyber Chase. At it's core, I think this illustration is valid. However, once we understand positives and negatives, we can begin to understand absolute value, which is where your thoughts come in. Thanks for sharing!